Avoiding repetitive checking of function output before storing into a dictionary
I've a repeating code block of iterating through inputs, checking some functions to return a list and the populating dictionary if the function did return a list, e.g.
def some_func(i):
    """ This function returns a filled list of a condition is met, otherwise an empty"""
    return ['abc', 'def'] if i % 2 == 0 else []

i_inputs = [4, 2, 3, 6, 3, 8, 2]
y1 = {}
for i in i_inputs:
    _x = some_funcs(i)
    if _x: 
        y1[i] = _x


The main problem is I'm having a lot of ys an i_inputs in my code, e.g.
i_inputs = [4, 2, 3, 6, 3, 8, 2]
y1 = {}
for i in i_inputs:
    _x = some_funcs(i)
    if _x: 
        y1[i] = _x


i_inputs2 = [8, 2, 4, 8, 9, 1]
y2 = {}
for i in i_inputs2:
    _x = some_funcs2(i) # Sometimes another function that also returns a list.
    if _x: 
        y2[i] = _x


i_inputs3 = [4, 8, 2, 9, 9, 1, 5]
y3 = {}
for i in i_inputs3:
    _x = some_funcs3(i) # Yet another function that also returns a list.
    if _x: 
        y3[i] = _x

Is there a better way other than enumerating all the i_input* and the y* in a hard-coded manner?

If you see repetitive patterns in your code, define a function that implements that pattern.

"populating dictionary if the function did return a list". Your code doesn't check whether it returned a list. [] is a list, but it doesn't put that in the dictionary. It checks whether it returned a truthy value. That's a number other than 0, a non-empty list, a non-empty string, etc.

Thanks for the notes in the comments! Let me try to abstract it in my codebase and see whether there's some nasty work in the different some_funcs* that causes issue; if it does, it'll be out of scope of this question though =)

Abtract the pattern in a function:
def dict_nonempty(func, l):
    d = {}
    for i in l:
        ret = func(i)
        if ret:
            d[i] = ret

    return d

y1 = dict_nonempty(some_funcs, i_inputs)
y2 = dict_nonempty(some_funcs2, i_inputs2)
y3 = dict_nonempty(some_funcs3, i_inputs3)

